# commandline interface (CLI) for the interpreter of Overpass-API

Tags: command-line-interface, overpass-api

I created an instance of the Overpass in a VirtualBox, with an http-server, the overpass-api-dispatcher and downloaded the openstreetmap data.
Everything works fine, i get results when i use it in a browser/wget/.. .

But. My machine isn't capable enough to create everytime an answer in less then 30 seconds, so i get often timeouts. When i increase timeout-time in the official overpass-PythonLib, i get another exceptions. I think because of tcp- or http-timeouts.

My question is, how can i start the interpreter directly, without the http- and tcp-levels between?
Like

> overpass-api/osm-3s_v0.7.53/cgi-bin/interpreter --data "[out:json]\;way[......]..."

At the moment, when i try do this, i get no response of the interpreter-program. It's even not listed in the list of processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `osm3s_query` binary instead:

`bin/osm3s_query < my_query > my_query_result`

You need to make sure that the dispatcher process has been started beforehand.

Comment: calling `bin/osm3s_query <query .... </query` throws an error `syntax error near unexpected token `<'`   I've passed `my_query` as a variable as well. What's the correct syntax to get output in the terminal?

Comment: my_query is a filename in this case, which contains the query. Osm3s_query reads the query from stdin.